# Annotation or keyword to tell garbage collector of objects to remove first

Tags: java, garbage-collection, keyboard, annotations

There is an annotation or a keyword in Java that tells the garbage collector to remove some objects first when the memory is running out.

Unfortunately I've forgotten it's name. Do you know it?

Comment: Are you referring to `null`? Typically, if you nullify your objects (and its references), it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Never heard of it; don't think it exists; google "java garbage collection annotation" turns up nothing interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm safe in saying that your memory's in error.  You may be thinking of [reference objects](http://www.iqlab.at/oscms/studium/staticFiles/java/java6docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).

Comment: Specifically, of SoftReference objects, which may be collected when memory is running out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't even see how you would annotate an object. Annotations are a compile time thing and objects are a runtime thing.

Perhaps you meant to say something like "how do I annotate a class to tell the garbage collector to collect objects of this class before any other objects".

I've never heard of such feature though.

Perhaps you're thinking of some cache eviction algorithms:

- least recently used (LRU),
- least frequently used (LFU), or
- first in first out (FIFO)

In that case, have a look at the EHCache library.